# Copying Assets to Web root folder instead of Web/Bundles

Tags: php, symfony

I have Symfony project in which i want to copy images to web folder. So I used bellow command.

php app/console assets:install web

It copy all images to Web/bundles/framework. I want all images in Web root folder.
Please suggest me how can i change the path to store all images or assets to root folder of web instead of storing in bundles.

Comment: Why would you want to store images and assets in the root? Won't that get rather  clunky?

Comment: actually I want to store in Web folder not in bundles because of some issues:(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, because the default `bundles/` directory is hardcoded in the source code:

**Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\AssetsInstallCommand - Line 83**

```
$bundlesDir = $targetArg.'/bundles/';
```

So I suggest either sticking to that convention or submitting a PR to the Symfony core repository to parametrize this directory.

Comment: or is it possible with assetic. It will store assets in images folder instead of root.When i run app/console assetic:dump --watch

Comment: One thing is *installing* the assets and another one is *dumping* them. They are not related at all. Of course, you can change the directory you want your assets dumped using the `assetic.write_to` configuration option.